# WP8 - Integrating Marketplace (Store) review with default 5 star

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, marketplace, rate

I've Implemented `MarketplaceReviewTask` into my Windows Phone 8 app.

(I know i can add `Rate-My-App` code which is pre-built library, but i wanted my own button for navigating user to the review page on store).

```
private void btnRageMe_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   MarketplaceReviewTask oRateTask = new MarketplaceReviewTask();
   oRateTask.Show();
}
```

When i've integrated "Rate-My-App" library into my app then the review page have default 5 stars selected.

now, when I'm integrating `MarketplaceReviewTask` then I can't find option to set default 5 star selected on the review page at the time of navigating there.

Any kind of help appreciated.

Comment: Could it be that you've rated the app with 5 stars before, so when you opened the review task it selected the stars which you already selected before, giving the impression that it was selected from the app? BTW, Rate-My-App is open source (with appropriate license, make sure to read it, of course), so maybe there's something there that can clarify this for you? https://github.com/nokia-developer/rate-my-app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I have just tried this with an app which I haven't rated before and I know it used Rate-My-App to bug me to rate it.

I selected 'Rate with 5 stars', the Store opened, and the 5 stars were NOT preselected.

I've also looked at [the source code](https://github.com/nokia-developer/rate-my-app) for the Rate-My-App quickly and found nothing that's setting the stars value.

My guess is that you already reviewed the app with 5 stars before, so when you opened the review task, it preselected the number of stars which was already submitted before, giving you the impression that it was predefined from inside the app.

Comment: Oops...
It's my fault. I've checked in 5 apps but I've already rated all of them.

Comment: This is correct, there is no way to pre-set the ratings when calling the marketplace review task.